# How to export .x3d file(frp, paraView) as FBX with colour?

Tags: .fbx, vertex-colors

I am trying to export my .x3d model to FBX with the ultimate goal of importing to unity. The model has colours stored as vertex paint, so initially the model is white. When I add a colour attribute to the material, the proper coloured model is visible in the render mode but not in the layout mode. Also when I export it to FBX, I do not get any colour information.
There are several blogs on the internet but either are for older blender versions or do not work for me.
What would be the ideal pipeline for me to use?

[image]